# Need create dynamic form in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2syhv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My Requirement is to create a form with formFields array which is list of form fields I have created object for the formfields and had push to formgroup But I think I had missed at some place where the structure in UI is not correct pushing the formfields are not correct I have updated code in Stackblit

[image: Console error you can check this is image url here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of issues with your implementation. So I decided to create my own.

What you're looking for is to create a `FormArray` with `FormGroup`s, where each `FormGroup` has `FormControl`s that are dynamically created.

To do that, you can write your Component Class like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  formFields = [ ... ];

  public tablesForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tablesForm = this.fb.group({
      employees: this.fb.array([this.addEmployerDetails()])
    });
  }

  addEmployerDetails() {
    const employeeDetailsFormGroup = this.fb.group({});
    this.formFields.forEach(field => {
      employeeDetailsFormGroup.addControl(field.formControl, this.fb.control([]));
    });
    return employeeDetailsFormGroup;
  }

  addEmployerToFormArray() {
    this.employeeRows.push(this.addEmployerDetails());
  }

  get employeeRows() {
    return (<FormArray>this.tablesForm.get('employees'));
  }

}
```

We're creating the `FormGroup` in `ngOnInit` where we are also calling `addEmployerDetails` which would return a `FormGroup` based on the `formFields`.

`addEmployerToFormArray` would add a new `FormGroup` to your `tablesForm` `FormGroup`, and would be called from the Template on click of `Add Employer` div.

`employeeRows` `get`er would also be used both in Template and the Component Class itself.

And in your Template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row pad-leftright">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div (click)="addEmployerToFormArray()">
                <span><i class="fa fa-plus plus-icon"></i></span>
        <span class="emp-title">Add Employer</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="tablesForm">
    <div class="row pad-leftright">
      <div>
        <table class="table ft-table simple-table table-equal-columns" border="1">
          <thead class="theader">
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let x of formFields">{{x.name}}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of employeeRows.controls; let ind = index;">
              <td formArrayName="employees" *ngFor="let field of formFields">
                <div [formGroupName]="ind">
                  <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input [type]="field.type" class="form-control" id="example-input-3" [placeholder]="field.name" [formControlName]="field.formControl" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-table-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you very much bro